# Webpack not including component html files after Angularjs2 project build

Tags: html, angularjs, angular, webpack

I am trying to build Angularjs2 project with webpack. In the output directory I am getting app.bundle.js file and index.html. But it doesn't include html file required in components.

Am I missing something? I am new to webpack. Please advise.

My project structure
[image]

webpack.config
[image]

tsconfig

[image]

Comment: You should post your code instead of including screenshots, that would be a lot more readable and avoid broken links in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should add raw-loader:

```
npm i raw-loader --save-dev

loaders:[
...
{test: /\.css$/, loader: 'raw-loader'},
{test: /\.html$/, loader: 'raw-loader'}
]

extensions: [
        '', '.ts', '.js', '.css', '.html'
]
```

Comment: Added raw-loader. Still it didn't load html files.